# Dependent and independent vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The  indexed family  $u_{1},u_{2}$ where $u_{1}=u_{2}  \neq \vec{0}$ are  linearly dependent ( because $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ are collinear) and  linearly independent at the same time ! we have  $\alpha _{1}u_{1} +\alpha_{2}u_{2}=(\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2})u_{2}=\alpha u_{2}=\vec{0} \Rightarrow  \alpha=0$
what's wrong?I know that this impossible but I can't find the flaw.help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)=(1,-1)$ gives $u-v=0$, which is one possible non-trivial linear relation. So a vector is *not* linearly independent from itself.

---

Note that it is somewhat common for textbooks to define linear (in)dependence for *sets* of vectors -- what they really should be talking about here is *indexed families* of vectors. If you're restricting yourself to *sets*, then you can't even speak about whether $v$ and $u$ are linearly independent when $v=u$, because then $\{v,u\}=\{v,v\}=\{v\}$. With an indexed family this problem goes away.

In the case of finitely many vectors we can speak of simply ordered *tuples* of vectors rather than indexed families. This is usually -- more or less implicitly -- the case when we're speaking about bases.